# How to change URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my htaccess file for showing a company profile:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/home\ view_details.php
```

And this code is working fine with this url

```
http://www.example.com/zoom-international-fcz-/home.html
```

Now I need to rewrite with this URL, not need to add `home.html`, and `zoom-international-fcz` is not a static string, it's coming dynamically....

```
http://www.example.com/zoom-international-fcz/
```

Comment: So basically you want what you have now, but without the `home.html` part? Just remove `home` from the expression then.

Comment: Thanks, actually home.html is the reference string for view_details.php,after removing home.html, it's now redirecting to view_details.php

Comment: Then I guess you need to fix that script as well.

Comment: So basically remove the end slash and the home.html?

Comment: After doing this,The other rewrite URL are conflicting and giving errors

Comment: ^(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)$ view_details.php?slug=$2 Probably a little too wild. Can you show the rules you already have.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\.htm$ $1.html

RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/profile\.html temprof.php

RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/products\.html products.php

RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/contacts\.html tem_enquiry.php

RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/enquiry\.html tem_enquiry.php

Answer (score 2):

Example of a dynamic rewrite rule

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^files/([^/]+)/([^/]+).zip /download.php?section=$1&file=$2 [NC]
```

would allow you to present this link as..

http://site.pl/files/games/file.zip

the two regular expressions in () are put into $1 and $2 and these params are available in your **$_GET** variable on download.php site.

Comment: i need only 
http://site.pl/files, and files is a slug which is coming form database, by this slug i get the ID and showing the content on the page.

Comment: RewriteRule ^files/ /download.php [NC] it will redirect from site.com/files to /download.php

Comment: Thanks, but i already asked, i don't want to show any static string like files on my URL.

Comment: I don't want to give any reference word on my htaccess code, like

RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+)\/home\ view_details.php or RewriteRule ^demo\/([a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+) view_details.php

i want when this type of URL came

www.example.com/one/
www.example.com/two/
www.example.com/three/
www.example.com/four/

it's automatically  configure veiw_deaitls.php  file, so i cat get the one,two,three slugs ID from the database by name